# Why does drive not enter standby mode when using hdparm -S

Tags: power-management

When reading the `hdparm` manual pages, it says that the `-S` value

> is used by the drive to determine how long to wait (with no disk
>   activity) before  turning  off  the  spindle motor to save power

When configuring my drives with `hdparm -B 1 -K 1 -S 120 /dev/sd[d-z]` the output is:

> ```
>  setting drive keep features to 1 (on)
>  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0x01 (1)
>  setting standby to 120 (10 minutes)
>  APM_level    = 1
> ```

And initial drive state `hdparm -C /dev/sd[d-z]` is "*active/idle*".

All these `/dev/sd[d-z]` drives are off the same make and model, not partitioned, not formatted and not mounted.

After **waiting for 15 minutes**, the drive state is still "*active/idle*".

Only when issuing a "Force  an  IDE  drive to immediately enter the low power consumption standby mode" using `hdparm -y /dev/sd[d-z]` the drive go to a "*standby*" state.

**Why do my drives not enter the low power consumption standby state** after the hdparm specified timeout value?

---

Some more drive specs derived from `hdparm -I /dev/sdd`

```
/dev/sdd:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630                 
    Firmware Revision:  MZ4OAAB0
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0; Revision: ATA8-AST T13 Project D1697 Revision 0b
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = 22756 KBytes (type=DualPortCache)
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5700
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 1
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
            Media Card Pass-Through
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    URG for READ_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
       *    URG for WRITE_STREAM[_DMA]_EXT
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            unknown 119[7]
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    NCQ priority information
            Non-Zero buffer offsets in DMA Setup FIS
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
            In-order data delivery
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
    not supported: enhanced erase
    416min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000cca37dc106a3
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000cca
    Unique ID   : 37dc106a3
Checksum: correct
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After disabling SMART scrubbing (automatic offline testing), with `smartctl --offlineauto=off /dev/sdx` the drive is now entering "*standby*".

Note: offlineauto=off value is saved in the drive, surviving reboots and power outages.

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/458512/why-does-unpartitioned-hitachi-hds5c3020-drive-start-consuming-50-more-power-15/#answer-458528